# Why doesn't Popen.communicate() return the output after the "||" operator?

Tags: python, bash, macos, subprocess

```py
import subprocess

cmd = "source ~/.bash_profile || echo hello"
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                        shell=True)
(out, err) = proc.communicate()
code = proc.returncode
print(f"code:{code}, out:{out}, err:{err}")
```

Output:

> code:1, out:b'', err:b'/bin/sh: /Users/xxx/.bash_profile: No such file or directory\n'

I have no bash_profile, but why doesn't `out` contain `"hello"`?

Comment: this seems more like a bash problem than a python problem

Comment: Is this on MacOS?  Are you using bash or zsh?  Your code works as expected on Linux.

Comment: @TimRoberts I was about to say the same thing, the code prints `code:0, out:b'hello\n', err:b'/bin/sh: 1: source: not found\n'` (as expected) using bash on debian 10

Comment: yes, It's on MacOS

Comment: @jemand771 It is related to Python because when you directly execute `source ~/.bash_profile_does_not_exist || echo hello` on a macOS terminal, you see *both* the error *and* the "hello" string. But when you put it in a Python script like this with `subprocess`, the "hello" indeed does not appear.

Comment: @yuehaozhao Can you [edit] in your env info? Python version, macOS version, bash version. And I assume you are running this Python script directly on the Terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be difference between `bash` and `sh`
You can reproduce it without python. It also makes sense python relies on `/bin/sh` by default, so it exposes the behavior

```
#!/bin/sh
. abc || echo hello 
 # output: ./test.sh: line 3: .: abc: file not found

#!/bin/bash    
. abc || echo hello
# output: ./test.sh: line 3: abc: No such file or directory
# hello
```

probably changing the default setting to `/bin/bash` by the `executable` argument can somehow correct it

```
cmd = "source ~/.bash_profile || echo hello"
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd,
                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                        shell=True,
                        executable="/bin/bash")
```

Comment: but why? I need source to get env path?

Comment: I suspect this is simply because the `#!/bin/sh` is causing `bash` to run in posix mode.  You'll get similar behavior with `#!/bin/bash --posix`

Comment: @WilliamPursell That's true

Answer (score 1):

This behavior does not seem to be documented in the `bash` man page, but the open standard states: `If no readable file is found, a non-interactive shell shall abort; an interactive shell shall write a diagnostic message to standard error, but this condition shall not be considered a syntax error.`  (https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_18_01)  When running non-interactively from python, the shell is simply aborting and not running the code after the `||`